# Strip HTML except for the text and a specific attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<div class="set">
    <span data-prefix="[1]">Duck</span>
    <span data-prefix="[2]">Dog</span>
    <span data-prefix="[3]">Cat</span>
</div>
```

I need Regex to strip all of the HTML except for the value of `data-prefix`.

So the expected output should be:

```
[1]Duck[2]Dog[3]Cat
```

I can't figure out how to do this, how can I?

Comment: Why do you need regExp? cant u do it in JS?

Comment: Sure, how can I do it in JS?

Comment: You [probably shouldn't be parsing HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4633828)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use [regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You can simply use JavaScript in this case.

Iterate over the elements with `data-prefix` attributes and access the attribute value with `dataset.prefix`. Then concatenate that with the `textContent` property value:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.set > [data-prefix]'),
    result = '';

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  result += elements[i].dataset.prefix + elements[i].textContent;
}

console.log(result); // [1]Duck[2]Dog[3]Cat
```

---

If you absolutely have to use regular expressions, I suppose you could use the following:

```
/(?:<span data-prefix="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/span>)+/g
```

It would return the following: [(example)](https://regex101.com/r/fG3vQ8/1)

```
1) ([1])(Duck)
2) ([2])(Dog)
3) ([3])(Cat)
```

Comment: +1 for parsing HTML with regex link. That's what comes to mind when any SO browser who's seen that finds somebody attempting to do so.. ;)

Comment: Looks nice, however I do have spans that do NOT have a data-prefix attribute. How can I have those included in the results too? (pretty much just a span with a letter)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get all the dom nodes with the data-X

var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-prefix]'),
    values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    values.push(nodes[i].dataset.prefix + nodes.textContent);
}
```

Now you have a n array with all the values that you need.

Answer (score 0):

> however I do have spans that do NOT have a data-prefix attribute. How can I have those included in the results

This code [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/uzu4pwqn/2/) select all `span` within the parent `div.set`, grabs its attribute `data-prefix` and if it is there it'll output it, otherwise it outputs `[-]` instead

```js
var divSpans = document.querySelectorAll('.set > span');

for (var i = 0; i < divSpans.length; i++) {
  var prefix = divSpans[i].getAttribute('data-prefix'),
    divHTML = divSpans[i].textContent;

  prefix = (prefix) ? prefix : '[-]';

  divSpans[i].innerHTML = prefix + divHTML;

}
```

```html
<div class="set">
  <span data-prefix="[1]">Duck</span>
  <span data-prefix="[2]">Dog</span>
  <span data-prefix="[3]">Cat</span>
  <span>Falcon</span>
  <span data-prefix="[4]">Parrot</span>
</div>
```